# Password validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, forms, validation

[https://secure.www.cartier.cn/zh-cn/服务/my-cartier/RegistrationStep1.html](https://secure.www.cartier.cn/zh-cn/%E6%9C%8D%E5%8A%A1/my-cartier/RegistrationStep1.html)
I am using below RegEx to validate my password using jQuery validation.

```
$.validator.addMethod("passwordTest", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^(?=.*\d)[0-9a-zA-Z\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\)\(\+\=\.\_\-\?\}\{\]\[\>\<\"\\\/\'\:\;]{8,}$/i.test(value);
        }, _objPropertiesMsg.passWeak);
```

Rules applied on password validation as mentioned in CARE-8804:

```
min 8 alphanumerical chars
combination of letters & numbers
no consecutive repeat of a char more than 2 times
```

It is working till 8 characters but above 8 characters all validations fails.
Also it fails for 2 consecutive char check and accepting 8 only numbers.

Comment: check this link - RegEx...https://regex101.com/r/hE7lN6/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is generally not a good idea, to try to check all your conditions in just one regex.

Instead, just check for length with pure javascript, have a regex checking for characters not occurring more than twice in a row and another one making sure that there is at least one digit followed by a non-digit or the other way around:

```
$.validator.addMethod("passwordTest", function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || value.length>=8 && /^((.)\2?(?!\2))+$/i.test(value) && /(\d[^\d]|[^\d]\d)/.test(value);
        }, _objPropertiesMsg.passWeak);
```

Have a loom at a proof of concept at https://jsfiddle.net/jvL151ya/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its taking special characters also. For example !@test12 and !@test12test should fail.

Comment: I have added one more condition /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/i..test(value). and its validating fine.

Comment: I didnt get that condition the first time. But to make that work you do not have to add another condition. Just replace `(.)` with `[a-z0-9]` and only alphanumerical strings will be matched. Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/jvL151ya/1/ ... When using the `i`-modificator (make matching case insensitive) there is no need to have `A-Z` and `a-z` in the expression. One is enough and keeps it less complex. Also: You might want to rethink your decision not to allow special characters. Security wise it makes sense to allow them.